# Bootstrap dropdown list not opening in bs grid in Angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I have a bootstrap grid and in some cells there should be shown a dropdown component of bootstrap. Here is the code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            ...
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    <!-- other cells -->
                    <div *ngIf='col.type=="dropdown"' class="dropdown">
                       <!-- This dropdown
                        component
                        is not opened
                        inside my grid-->
                        <!--Dropdown Code starts-->
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--Dropdown Code ends-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it is shown like that:

[image]

However, if i click on dropdown buttons, their list does not become visible. If i use the same code in somewhere else in my component, it is working properly.

I get no error messages and bootstrap is correctly loaded (all other components also work). What can be wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember, Bootstrap Dropdowns use JQuery plugin and you have to initialize all your dropdowns by calling

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

What happens with Angular2, and specifically with `*ngIf` is that Angular recreates contents (in your case `<div class="dropdown">`) each time condition changes (you can see that when condition is not `true` whole internal HTML part is gone from page). Even when you load page contents doesn't exist and are created later... I.e. in your case initialization happens before grid-dropdown is rendered.

So I assume that you have to init Bootstrap dropdown every time your `col.type` changed.

Or you can try to bind to `<div [hidden]="col.type == 'dropdown'">` property instead... But still Dropdown Init has to be done on one of the `ngAfterViewInit`, `ngAfterContentInit`, `ngAfterContentChecked`, `ngAfterViewChecked` Lifecycle hooks of the component that contains these elements...

Anyway, I would propose you to use one of the existing Angular2-Dropdown libs instead...

Comment: `dropdown()` function solves the problem as you said. I was thinking about on which lifecycle hooks it should be binded but not sure. Currently, u have used `dropdown()` function within `ngDoCheck` function, it solves the problem but now the question is how efficient is that? Can you provide some information? You can edit your answer as it has worked for me so that i can accept your question. Thanks!

Comment: I completely agree that you should consider existing solution for dropdown as finally you will end up with reinventing wheel.

Comment: Problem with this jQuery function is that it bind `onclick` to all items with provided css selector on page. You can avoid it by assigning unique ID to each dropdown... Or reinitialize Selectboxes only when list of rows changed... Better solution will be writing Directive for selectbox, then use `ViewChild` to bind `dropdown()` directly to Directive template...

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called `ng2-bootstrap` which is developed by the   `angular-ui` team.
so i think it is  better to use it  than polluting the angular2 ecosystem with `jQuery` .
Here is the [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown)

Comment: good suggestion, beat me to the punch lol +1 I also recommend this approach by @Anoop